# Where are the AngularJS I18n files?

Tags: internationalization, angularjs, locale

They talk about locale-specific files here http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n but don't mention where to get them (the official AngularJS repo doesn't contain them).

So where does one obtain these locale files?

Answer (score 27):

You can also get them with **bower**:

```
bower install angular-i18n
```

It is the official bower distribution that mirrors the files at https://code.angularjs.org/

More info at https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-i18n

Answer (score 14):

Lastest stable version i18n files at here: 
http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.3/i18n/

You can also find other versions at here: 
http://code.angularjs.org/

Answer (score 2):

You can also get them with **npm**:

```
npm install angular-i18n
```

And then add the locale-File of your choice in your index.html:

```
<script src="/node_modules/angular-i18n/angular-locale_YOUR-LOCALE.js"></script>
```

Note that only the latest loaded locale-file will be used by your angular app.

It is also possible to change the locale dynamically with [angular-dynamic-locale](http://github.com/lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale). Then you don't need to decide on startup in the index.html which locale you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

First install all files from **bower**

```
bower install angular-i18n --save
```

or get angular-locale files for your required language-country from
https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-i18n

*then either do hard work and include all files in head in your script tags or just download*

> tmhDynamicLocale js

***(smart work)***, it dynamically include all angular-locale files.

Follow this git hub repository for demo

https://github.com/ajarvis98/angular-locale-tmh-dynamic-locale

Follow the structure exactly as in this git-repo