# Angular-translate and date formatter: how to translate month name?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, angular-translate

In my app i'm using `angular-translate`

https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate

for translating my content.

And also in my view i have such date formatter:

```
{{article.CreatedAt | date:'dd MMM yyyy':'UTC'}}
```

but when i set polish, russian (or any other language, non-english) - my month names are still in english.

**How can i translate them** (will be great, if this is doneable without momentum and other plugins...)?

Comment: try out this plunkr from a similar post http://plnkr.co/edit/AFpj79M1C6vOewSWLX8J

Comment: @Jared `will be great, if this is doneable without momentum and other plugins`.
second: i haven't any ui calendar...

Comment: They are using i18n and ngLocale, I dont think you need momentum.  Look at the ng-fr-ca.js file.

Comment: I think your question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937780/angularjs-translate-format-dynamic-dates

Comment: Have you loaded the locale for the languages that you are using? These contain the translations that you are seeking.  https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/master/src/ngLocale

Comment: @Jared i've loaded all this locations. But then it translate my month names depending on browser language. And this is wrong. It must translate due to angular-translate language settings.

Comment: Sounds like you need  to use angular-dynamic-locale so that you can set the locale at run time.  You cant set it at run time using ngLocale.

Comment: FWIW angular-translate does NOT translate any date or time settings, you must use ngLocale or angular-dynamic-locale to do that.  In your case you MUST use the latter, angular-dynamic-locale, to achieve your goal.  To my knowledge, there is no other way.  Link:  https://github.com/lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale

Comment: @Jared, ok, thank's, i'll try...

Comment: Is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937780/angularjs-translate-format-dynamic-dates what you are looking for?

Comment: @tomepejo no! it's not

Comment: You must take a look at this GitHub issue: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/master/src/ngLocale

Answer (score 6):

For changing application locale dynamically you need [angular-dynamic-locale](https://github.com/lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale) and you also need other locale files (english is coming with angular) from [ngLocale](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/master/src/ngLocale).

Here is working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5mmtDhf7JvRULMshjcag?p=preview).

You need to catch translate events as we want to change locale when language is changed. So for this purpose I used `$translateChangeSuccess` event to set selected language as new locale.

```
$rootScope.$on('$translateChangeSuccess', function (event, data) {
    tmhDynamicLocale.set(data.language);
});
```

Here is the list of all [$translate events](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/18_events).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an external library, in angular, date and number format are translated using angular-i18n:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n

For example, to get date in russian, just include the locale file after angular:

```
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="angular-locale_ru-ru.js"></script>
```

Of course this will not be dynamic, you could manage it server-side, or find another trick.

to get it from bower, use

```
$ bower install angular-i18n
```

see [Where are the AngularJS I18n files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270405/where-are-the-angularjs-i18n-files)

Comment: no... it's a bad idea in my case (because i need to see month name without dot, from capital letter etc...)

Comment: If it is a dot from the format, you can provide your own: from the documentation: "'longDate': equivalent to 'MMMM d, y' for en_US locale (e.g. September 3, 2010)" so use 'MMMM'  to hav full month name. Maybe i don't understand your need and it is not enough, in that case, you may create your own translation inspired from the source code of the angular libraries: use $provide.value("$locale", {
  "DATETIME_FORMATS": {
    "AMPMS": [
      "AM",
      "PM"
    ],
    "DAY": [
      "dimanche",
      "lundi",
      "mardi",
      "mercredi",
      "jeudi",
      "vendredi",
      "samedi"
   ...